# Where does Soap UI look for a file in new File() Groovy Script by default? How do i change this?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a groovy script which reads the text from a file and returns it as a response

i have to read it as follows

```
text = new File("D:/text.xml")
```

now the problem is i'd like to use relative paths.. so i was wondering

If i just say

```
text = new File("text.xml")
```

Where does Soap UI / Groovy start searching for the file by default? This currently throws a "java.io.FileNotFoundException".

*How do i change this so that it uses paths relative to the project.xml file?*

**This is how i finally solved my requirement**

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath //gets the path of the project root
def response = new File(projectPath, "/test.xml").text;
```

Comment: re:file path, does the info in this post help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266525/how-can-i-use-relative-paths-to-external-response-files-for-soapui-mockservice ?

Comment: Absolutely, thats exactly what i found as well , thanks :)

Comment: awesome. happy to have been able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

or

```
System.out.println(text.getAbsolutePath());
```

to your script to find out.

Comment: AFAIK, the above is valid Groovy. And you already have a Groovy script running.

Comment: It currently looks inside the soap install folder , how do i make it look inside another folder, hopefully relative to the actual project.xml file?

Comment: Also how can i access a global property from within the groovy script? 

So that i could atleast append  it to each new File()?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Resource Root` Project Property in soapUI.

`${projectDir}` points to your project folder.

[image: Resource Root Project Property]